# How to prevent UiPath from getting stuck in Call Macro Stage?

Tags: vba, uipath

I am calling a macro using call macro in UiPath Workflow. The concern is some time one of the excels that the macro handles will freeze forever, Causing the macro execution to hang and the process will get stuck  in Call macro forever.

Is there some way I can modify the UiPath workflow so that, if the Call macro activity is not completed within 15 minutes, the bot throws an exception?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this, let me try to present it to you:

You will need 3 variables for your solution as per below:

1. One to store your wait time until exception will be thrown type of **TimeSpan**
2. One to declare your start time of your current execution type of **DateTime**
3. One to inform if the default wait time of execution was exceeded or not type of **Boolean**

[image]

Then you need to use **Parallel activity** where on your **Excel Application Scope** and **Execute Macro** will run together with a **While loop** that will constantly compare starting time and your set waiting time. If it will exceed the default time value set, an exception will be thrown. Check the solution example below:

[image]

In this case because we surround **Parallel** Action in **Try-Catch** block, you need to specify the exception expression in **Catches** section, since **Throw** will be overwritten by **Catches** as per below:

[image]

The second option is to do it without **Try-Catch** then the **Throw** exception will be displayed, check solution below:

[image]

Also you need to modify the **Throw** action by setting the exception message accordingly as per image below:

[image]

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: I tried the above code with a simple macro function which displays a message box. The message box is  popping up only when the timeout exception is thrown.

Comment: Will prarallel really work in this case? I feel it wont  because, when the macro is in execution, bot is executing the 'Execute Macro' activity. Only when the macro is finished it will come out of it.  So will it be able to switch to the other branch of parallel (while its executing the 'Execute Macro' stage)?

Comment: Yes it will work, the thing that needs to be added is to change the value of the  Boolean variable (excecutionMacroComplete)  to True if macro was successful. I have tried by placing the macro to wait for 2 minutes and the maxWaitTime variable to 1 minute. Keep in mind that if you wrap up the Parallel Action in Try-Catch block then whatever you set in Catch section will be displayed as exception if you do not use Try and Catch then Throw message will be displayed.

Comment: @automaticSoldier please check updated answer and comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your call macro in a parallel where you in a second branch have a delay and a Throw Exception. The delay should be your desired timeout value, i.e. 15 minutes.

You also need to have a local variable of type boolean as input to the [condition property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activities.statements.parallel.completioncondition?view=netframework-4.8) in the parallel. When/if the macro call returns you set this boolean to True which in turn cancels the delay branch.

This way, if the exception is thrown the parallel is exited and the workflow continues. Based on your desired behavior you may want to wrap the parallel in a try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @Konstantinos Palaiodimos is in the right direction but the branch 2 is having loop which would continuously execute until maxWaitTime and eventually would throw exception. So to ensure the control goes back to Branch 1(Excel scope) after timeout checking in Branch 2(Do while Loop) a delay need to be added to the Branch 2.
If there is a delay in branch 2 the control will go back to Branch 1 during that delay to check if macro execution is completed or not , if macro is not completed then again control comes back to branch 2 and the cycle continues until maxWaitTime or till the macro execution completes